# Migration to IdentityServer 4.1 and IDX10501 error

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, jwk

I'm currently trying a migration from IdentityServer 3.x to 4.1.1, and I have followed this
migration guide:

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.0/Migration-Guides/Abp-4_0

The problem is that I got an IDX10501 error now, please have a look at the full log here:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7452

My "old" tempkey.rsa files are still there but new files are generated "tempkey.jwk".

So, do you think it is related? and how can I change this?

At the end, my goal is just to fix this IDX10501 error... any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tempkey.jwk is generated by this command

```
builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

and this is fine for development but not in production.

The error you get is that the key is not found in the JWKS endpoint. You need to use the **AddSigningCredential** method to add your old key as the signing key.

The kid claim found in the tokens must match what you see from the **/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks** endpoint.